# Numero aleatorio con funcion random_device y mt19937 en c++

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema al intentar generar una clave unica con numeros aleatorios. Utilizo las funciones random_device y mt19937 para generarlo pero siempre que corro el programa me da el mismo numero. No importa si apago la pc o reinicio el IDE y aun sigue generando el mismo numero. Lo que intento generar es numeros aleatorios entre 1 y 10000000 osea numeros entre 1 y 8 cifras.

```
void registro(){
    string nombre, apellido, correo;
    int edad;

    random_device clave_aleatoria;
    mt19937 clave(clave_aleatoria());
    uniform_int_distribution <int> entre(1,10000000);//generar numeros aleatorios entre 1 y 8 cifras

    cout<<"\tRegistro de nuevos usuarios"<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese su nombre"<<endl;cin>>nombre;
    cout<<"Ingrese su apellido"<<endl;cin>>apellido;
    cout<<"Ingrese su edad"<<endl;cin>>edad;
    cout<<"Ingrese su correo electronico"<<endl;cin>>correo;


    cout<<"Su clave de registro es la siguiente:"<<entre(clave)<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que tengas, en alguna parte del programa, un problema con la gestión de la memoria, es decir, que en algún sitio estés pisando memoria y eso provoque el comportamiento que comentas

Comment: Prueba a hacer dos llamadas consecuivas a la función `std::cout << entre(clave) << '\n' << entre(clave) << '\n';` a ver si así cambia la contraseña o si, por el contrario, se ha quedado atascada en ese número. También podrías probar a crear un programa que únicamente genere la clave de la misma manera... si la secuencia obtenida es la misma que en tu programa entonces yo sospecharía que las librerías de tu IDE no funcionan correctamente

Comment: Fijate que realice lo que me indicas y coloque tres llamadas la funcion y si me genera numeros distintos en cada llamada. Lo que sucede es de que cuando cierro el programa o vuelvo a hacer las llamadas de la funcion me vuelve a dar los mismos tres numeros y esto sucede si vuelo a cerrar y abrir el IDE. Por cierto el ide que utilizo es Code Blocks es posible que sea por el ide

Comment: el ide es solo un entorno de desarrollo. Hay ide que solo funcionan con un compilador y hay otros más genéricos.  Codeblocks es genérico.  Prueba a reinstalar las librerías del compilador

Comment: El programa funciona para mi y muestra números distintos (después de añadir el `main`) . Pero ten en cuenta que no se garantiza que los números aleatorios sean siempre únicos.Para generar claves únicas verdaderas, se necesita una base de datos de claves usadas.